# LINQ: Why am I getting error on this LINQ Query?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-sql, repository

This my method in my repository:

```
    public List<Question> getallquestion()
    {
        var hej = from Core in db.CoreValue
                    join Question in db.Question on Core.CID equals question.QID
                    join Subject in db.SubjectType on Core.CID equals Subject.SID
                    select new
                    {
                        Core.Cname,
                        Question.QuestionText,
                        Subject.Sname
                    };

        return hej.ToList();

    }
```

This is the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'NKI3.Models.Question'
```

What is the solution for this error? I cant seem to find it

My CreateViewModel:

```
    public class CreateViewModel
    {
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public string Sname { get; set; }
        public string Cname {get;set;}

    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Best Regards!

Comment: Please show available public constructors of the `Question` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your select to read like so:

```
public List<CreateViewModel> GetAllQuestionViewModel()
    {
        var hej = from Core in db.CoreValue
                    join Question in db.Question on Core.CID equals question.QID
                    join Subject in db.SubjectType on Core.CID equals Subject.SID
                    select new CreateViewModel
                    {
                        Cname = Core.Cname,
                        QuestionText = Question.QuestionText,
                        Sname = Subject.Sname
                    };

        return hej.ToList();

    }
```

In your controller you would do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    IEnumerable<CreateViewModel> questions = someContext.GetAllQuestionViewModel();
    return View(questions);
}
```

Comment: I was guessing that it was the `Namespace` of the `Question` entity. You can just use `new Question` if you already have a using statement in your class.

Comment: My Question only have 2 properties and its QID and QuestionText. Sname comes from SubjectType table and Cname comes from CoreValue Table

Comment: If you could supply the code for the `CreateViewIndex` I could better answer your question.

Answer (score 5):

Your linq query produces List of anonymous object (as you use `select new { (...) }` without any type). You should replace it with `select new Question() { (...) }`. You should check that select syntax depending on Question class properties.

eg. When you have `Name`, `Text` and `Subject` property is should look like this:

```
    var hej = from c in db.CoreValue
                join q in db.Question on c.CID equals q.QID
                join s in db.SubjectType on c.CID equals s.SID
                select new Question
                {
                    QID = q.QID,
                    QuestionText  = q.QuestionText
                };
```

Comment: I got another error now when i changed it to what you said: Cannot initialize type 'NKI3.Models.Question' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: You should assign `Core.Cname`, `Question.QuestionText` and `Subject.Sname` values to Question class properties.

Comment: Could you tell me what properties does Question class contain?

Comment: I updated the answer. If the Question class contains only that 2 properties you can't include SubjectType value in there, as you tried on yous question.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is expecting to return a collection of your `Question` type, but your LINQ query is returning a sequence of an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). You should change your query, for example changing your projection:

```
public List<Question> getallquestion()
{
    var hej = from Core in db.CoreValue
                join Question in db.Question on Core.CID equals question.QID
                join Subject in db.SubjectType on Core.CID equals Subject.SID
                select new Question
                {
                    Name = Core.Cname,
                    Text = Question.QuestionText,
                    Subject = Subject.Sname
                };

    return hej.ToList();
}
```

This is using an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) to assign the property values of the `Question` type from the result of the query. Your property names will differ.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return an anonymous type.

Create a class

```
public class QuestionResult
{
 public string Core {get; set;}
 public string Question {get; set;}
 public string Subject{get; set;}
}
```

and use it

```
public List<QuestionResult> getallquestion()
    {
        var hej = from Core in db.CoreValue
                    join Question in db.Question on Core.CID equals question.QID
                    join Subject in db.SubjectType on Core.CID equals Subject.SID
                    select new QuestionResult
                    {
                        Core = Core.Cname,
                        Question = Question.QuestionText,
                        Subject = Subject.Sname
                    };

        return hej.ToList();

    }
```